# CamelContext must be specified on: HttpMessage@0x36ed8347

Tags: spring-boot, spring-camel

I am using camelServlet, camel kafka in a spring boot app, I am getting this error which I am not able to understand

when I try to call a get endpoint which is configured as REST DSL route I am getting the below error

Route:

```
rest().get("/getBatchID")
                .to("direct:getBatchID");
```

I have defined the camel servlet bean as below :

```
  @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean camelServletRegistrationBean() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CamelHttpTransportServlet(), "/camel/*");
        registration.setName("CamelServlet");
        return registration;
```

Stacktrace:

```
2018-11-25 23:22:10,066|INFO |http-nio-9000-exec-2|o.a.c.c.s.CamelHttpTransportServlet - Initialized CamelHttpTransportServlet[name=CamelServlet, contextPath=]
2018-11-25 23:22:10,183|ERROR|http-nio-9000-exec-2|o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[CamelServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [CamelServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CamelContext must be specified on: HttpMessage@0x36ed8347
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(ObjectHelper.java:342)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultMessage.createHeaders(DefaultMessage.java:254)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultMessage.setHeader(DefaultMessage.java:171)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpMessage.<init>(HttpMessage.java:41)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doService(CamelServlet.java:169)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:74)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

Do I need to add camelContext in the header while making a get request ??

Comment: Any updates on this, were you able to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem occurs because HTTPMessage extends DefaultMessage which exists in same package in more then 1 jar dependency.

class `org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultMessage` exists in 2 jars.

1. Active-MQ All
2. Camel core JAR.

Solution is you use activemq-client jar or adjust your .MF file